# How can I get the \rhead superiorly to the top and \chead down?

Tags: header, latex, tex

### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}



\newlength{\tabcont}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.05in}


\title{Assignment 4}


\newcommand{\course}{lipsum}
\newcommand{\coursen}{lipsum}
\newcommand{\semester}{lipsum}
\newcommand{\TDAG}{lipsum}
\newcommand{\campus}{lipsum}
\newcommand{\dept}{lipsum}



\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\headheight 56.2pt

\chead{\campus \\ \dept \\ \course \\ \coursen }
\lhead{\TDAG}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Submit the following problems which are given in the tutorial 4 as your Assignment 4.
\begin{enumerate}

\item In question 19 ,part (d).
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

### The solution I want

After compiling the above document, the `\rhead` and `\chead` are similar in position of height. I want the `\rhead` to be up and `\chead` to be down/after `\rhead`.

I have reviewed a post that included something like `\header[C]`, but that did not work. I am using Miktex + texMaker. But **do provide an example if you know how to do it with** `\header[C]` :)

## Screenshots

### Current one

[What I get when I compile the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1rv7.png)

### The solution that I need

[I need code to get this look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLC0M.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just wrap the central header in a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 


\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}



\newlength{\tabcont}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.05in}


\title{Assignment 4}


\newcommand{\course}{lipsum}
\newcommand{\coursen}{lipsum}
\newcommand{\semester}{lipsum} 
\newcommand{\TDAG}{lipsum}
\newcommand{\campus}{lipsum}
\newcommand{\dept}{lipsum}



\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\headheight 56.2pt

\chead{\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\campus \\ \dept \\ \course \\ \coursen 
\end{minipage}}
\lhead{\TDAG}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Submit the following problems which are given in the tutorial 4 as your Assignment 4.
\begin{enumerate}

\item In question 19 ,part (d).
\end{enumerate}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is interesting as well. But This has been answered by @egreg in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/606537/247020